# What do I do wrong with documentclass{apa6}

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, apacite, apa6

On a MacBookPro 2023, Sonoma 14.4 running MacTex2023 I can't get apa functions get to work; (biber and biblatex give \endcsname missing, impossible for me to comprehend; so I step to natbib and BibTeX but have also serrors that I do not understand)

I need to (re)produce apa documents and would like to apply documentclass{apa6}.
Next to the general options [doc, font and paper size,..] I specify the recommended options [ ...,babel, dutch, american, natbib] (ref apa6.pdf).

natbib loads the package apacite and there is no need to specify the \bibliographystyle
in the .tex file as this is done by the apa6 class.

I deliberately apply the PassOptionsToPackage to invoke apacite citation commands
(however omitting this makes no difference to the problems that occurs)

It requires four(!!) runs to get the final document.

But the LaTex runs show errors:

run 1) Latex gives
three natbib warnings on natbib recognized citation commands,
and two Undefined control sequence errors on *apaciteclassic* citation commands. I continue with ENTERs to finish the erroneous pdf-output to get appropriate input for the Bibtex run (i.e. aux file)

run 2) Bibtex results
I have five lines of status info but no warnings and no errors

run 3) Latex gives
again 3 natbib warnings and two Undefined control sequence errors; but there is a correct reference table in the PDF output

run 4) Latex gives
only two errors on the apacite citation commands \citeA and \citeNP
these are not recognized.

The basic question is how to get apacite citation commands in scope, any ideas; thanks

The bib file

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/

%% Created for Ben Jutten at 2024-03-18 09:55:52 +0100 


%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



@incollection{Bereiter2002,
    author = {Bereiter, C.},
    booktitle = {Liberal education in a knowledge society},
    editor = {Smith, B.},
    publisher = {Chicago: Open Court},
    title = {Education in a knowledge society},
    year = {2002}}

@book{Kreijns2020,
    author = {Kreijns, K.},
    date-added = {2020-07-11 19:13:57 +0200},
    date-modified = {2020-07-11 19:18:03 +0200},
    month = {03},
    publisher = {Open Universiteit},
    title = {{Online Samenwerkend Leren en Social Presence}},
    year = {2020}}


@article{Scardamalia1993,
    author = {Scardamalia, M. and Bereiter, C.},
    journal = {Communications of the ACM},
    number = {5},
    pages = {37-41},
    title = {Technologies for knowledge-building discourse},
    volume = {36},
    year = {1993}}
```

and the .tex file

```
% Documentclass apa6
% option babel must be immediately followed by the desired language(s), the last is the main language
% option natbib, implicitly loads apacite and applies mask option to apa6
% NB do not specify \bibliographystyle as this is done by the apacite class that is loaded by natbib option in apa6 class
\PassOptionsToPackage{apaciteclassic}{apacite}
\documentclass[doc, 12pt, a4paper, babel, dutch, american, natbib]{apa6}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 
 
% the title commands; we need some otherwise it does not 'compile' 
\title{The Title of the document.}
\shorttitle{subject of this document}
\author{The author's name}
\affiliation{the institute}
\abstract{This abstract is dummy just to fill some some text in order to show that the field is there. }

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Citing Examples}
\subsection{Natbib cite commands}
command \textbackslash{}citet  ( year parenthesized)  gives: \citet[p.10-20]{Bereiter2002}, 

command \textbackslash{}citep whole reference parenthesized gives: \citep[p.27]{Kreijns2020},


\subsection{APA cite commands}

APA  \textbackslash{}cite gives: \cite{Scardamalia1993},  <<probably natbib's cite

APA \textbackslash{}citeA gives: \citeA[p.30-35]{Bereiter2002}, << cmd not recognized

APA \textbackslash{}citeNP gives:  \citeNP{Kreijns2020} << cmd not recognized


% print the reference information (style comes from apacite class)
\bibliography{learn.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need to switch to natbib, you just need to remove `\DeclareLanguageMapping{}{}` from your biblatex document.

Comment: Back to biber and biblatex by removing \DeclareLanguageMapping is - after all -simple and successfull; that is fine; However the reported issue in this question remains. Why are the (fragile) apacite citation commands not available.